# Files from other branches visible in master branch

Tags: git

I am learning git. I created a new `NEW` branch from my master branch and created a new file in `NEW`. Now when I switch back to master, the newly created file in `NEW` is visible in master branch. Is it normal? If so, how do I hide files from other branches in master branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until you add it (`git add <file>`) and you commit it (`git commit -m 'My new file'`), your newly created file isn't *tracked*. It means that git is not aware of its existence in its index tree.

So the behaviour you describe is totally expected. This [schema](http://assets.osteele.com/images/2008/git-transport.png) might help you to understand ([source](http://blog.osteele.com/posts/2008/05/my-git-workflow)).

Try the following:

```
git checkout master          # start from the master branch
git checkout -b NEW          # create and switch onto the NEW branch
echo foo > bar               # create a new file
git add bar                  # track the file
git commit -m 'My new file'  # Commit the new file
git checkout master          # The file has disappeared from the working directory
```

Comment: Exactly. I am doing same thing. Thanks for the reply.